# SCNRenderer snapshot doesn't always apply antialiasing

Tags: macos, cocoa, 3d, scenekit

Here's the problem. To the left is what I see in my scnView. To the right is what I get from SCNRenderer's `snapshot` of that scene. I'm on Catalina.

[image]

I have a scene and a way in the UI to make a snapshot of that scene. Here's how I do it

```
snapshotRenderer.scene = scnView.scene    
snapshotRenderer.snapshot(atTime: mySceneTime, with: mySize, antialiasingMode: SCNAntialiasingMode.multisampling4X)
```

### What I tried

My theory is that the `snapshot` method grabs the rendered content before the full render cycle is over, and all antialiasing samples are done (if any at all). The theory is based on the fact that I do see the same rough edges in my `scnView` for a second until the antialiasing is applied.

So, without luck, I've tried to trigger a cycle with

```
snapshotRenderer.scene!.isPaused = false
snapshotRenderer.isPlaying = false
```

and

```
self.snapshotRenderer.update(atTime: mySceneTime)
```

and also a `SCNTransaction.begin()` and `.commit()`. But nothing works.

I also tried waiting 3 seconds with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` after the above attempts, and then calling the snapshot. That didn't work either.

Comment: Does the view has `isJitteringEnabled` set to `true`? The screenshot seems to have antialiasing enabled, but maybe that's just because the image was downsized when it got uploaded there.

Comment: It looks like this is it! Thanks. I'll approve this as an answer if you create it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the view has `isJitteringEnabled` set to `true`? The screenshot seems to have antialiasing enabled, but maybe that's just because the image was downsized when it got uploaded there.